# replace 'spaces' from bigquery table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table

```
#standardSQL
with table as (
  select 'DE' country, 520 number union all
  select 'de' country, 480 number union all
  select ' DE' country, 500 number union all
  select ' DE   ' country, 500 number
)
select replace(UPPER(country), ' ', '') as country_shop, number from table
GROUP BY country, number
```

my current result looks like

```
row country_shop    number
1   DE              520
2   DE              480
3   DE              600
4   DE              400
```

I am trying to get the result as

```
row country_shop    number
1   DE              2000
```

Could someone please help me here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to group by the *country_shop* AND the *number* column but as we can see, this is not the result you want. You only want to `group by` the *country_shop* and `sum` all the numbers associated with that country.

Great, you already have functions that exist to remove all leading and trailing spaces called `trim` and another function called `sum`, you can then build a query like this:

```sql
select 
    upper(trim(country)) as country_shop,
    sum(number) as total_number
from table
group by country_shop
```

Please, read the [following documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) with all the functions already provided by bigquery to find the ones that suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use below instead

```
#standardSQL
with table as (
  select 'DE' country, 520 number union all
  select 'de' country, 480 number union all
  select ' DE' country, 500 number union all
  select ' DE   ' country, 500 number
)
select replace(UPPER(country), ' ', '') as country_shop, sum(number) number from table
GROUP BY country_shop
```

with output

[image]